# Ruby, Tor and Net::HTTP::Proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, tor, net-http

My apologies in advance if this is a noobish doubt: I want to use a proxy in my Ruby code to fetch a few web pages. And I want to be sneaky about it! So I am using Tor.

I have Tor running, and I am able to use Net::HTTP.get(uri) as usual. But I can't figure out how to use Net::HTTP::Proxy to fetch the uri. I also can't figure out how using Tor will help make my fetches anonymous.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please don't just add a [link to the ruby-doc page for Net::HTTP::Proxy](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-Proxy). If I had understood that, I would not be asking this here :-)

---

Another easy way to do this is using [SOCKSify](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/), but in this case, I receive the following error:

`/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2-p290/gems/socksify-1.5.0/lib/socksify.rb:189:in 'socks_authenticate': SOCKS version  not supported (SOCKSError)`

I have never done any network programming before. Any guidance about this will also be very helpful. Thanks :-)

Comment: How about a link to [Net::HTTP::Proxy](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP/Proxy/class)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Link added in question.

Comment: Definately interesting undertaking. I am looking forward to possible solutions.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The docs seem straightforward.

Comment: When the Tor browser is running, I can see my "apparent" IP address. Since this is the address through which I want to pass all the HTTP requests, I do `proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy('address.given.by.Tor',8080)` ... but, then, when I do `proxy.start('www.google.com') { |http| <print the response code> }`, nothing happens. I have to hit Ctrl+C eventually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using HTTP proxy class, so you must provide IP of HTTP proxy. Tor Browser has **not** HTTP proxy bundled.

So you can either install some proxy software e.g. [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) and configure it to use Tor's SOCKS:

In *config.txt*
 `forward-socks4a   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .`

then use Privoxy's default *listen-address* in your script:

```
proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy('127.0.0.1',8118)
```

**or** use SOCKSify.
According to [docs](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/):

```
require 'socksify/http'
uri = URI.parse('http://rubyforge.org/')
Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 9050).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  http.get(uri.path)
end
```

No need for additional software..

**Third** solution is to use SOCKSify as follows:

```
$ socksify_ruby localhost 9050 script.rb
```

which redirect all TCP connections of a Ruby script, which means you don't need to use any Proxy code at all.

*For clarification you have to understand that 127.0.0.1:9050 is Tor's SOCKS address and 127.0.0.1:8118 is address of Privoxy.*