# How to use SOCKSify proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, socks

I try to proxy traffic of a ruby application over a SOCKS proxy using ruby 2.0 and SOCKSify 1.5.0.

```
require 'socksify/http'

uri  = URI.parse("www.example.org")
proxy_addr = "127.0.0.1"
proxy_port = 14000

puts Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port).get(uri)
```

This is the minimal working example. Obviously it doesn't work but I think it should. I receive no error messages executing the file, it doesn't stop so I have to abort it manually. I have tried the solution after I found it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13882749/586014) (the code in that answer is different, but as mentioned above I first adapted it to my match my existing non-proxy-code and afterwards reduced it)

The proxies work, I tested both *tor* and `ssh -D` connection on my own webserver and other websites.

As rubyforge seems to be no longer existing, I can't access the [SOCKSify documentation on it](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/). I think the version might be outdated, does not work with ruby 2.0 or something like that.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there an alternative to SOCKSify?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the documentation for [`Net::HTTP#Proxies`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net%3a%3aHTTP-label-Proxies) gives an example we can base our code on. Also note the addition of the `.body` method, also found in the documentation.

Try this code:

```
require 'socksify/http'
uri = URI.parse('http://www.example.org/')
proxy_addr = '127.0.0.1'
proxy_port = 1400
Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  puts http.get(uri.path).body
end
```